# How to structure association between users and posts, if we need to track users' interaction with posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have an app that only displays posts that people haven't seen before so everytime a user opens an article, I need to set the seen_flag to true for this user/post combination.

Is the right approach to set it as a M:M relationship with the join table storing that interaction? Or should it still be 1:M?

EDITTED

Here are my associations between user and article. An user can create an article, but many users can view an articles, and and article has many viewed users, so I need both a `has_many through` and `belongs_to` association

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :viewed_users, through: :article_view_histories
  has_many :article_view_histories
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  has_many :viewed_articles, through: :article_view_histories
  has_many :article_view_histories
end

class ArticleViewHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :viewed_users, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :user_id
  belongs_to :viewed_articles, :class_name => "Article", :foreign_key => :article_id
end
```

Comment: It is a many to many relationship, and should therefore be split with a junction table if you want a normalised database.

Comment: It's a m:m relationship indeed, but beware of the number of rows this will generate. You also have to create efficient queries to retreive unread messages. Perhaps a gem like [unread](https://github.com/ledermann/unread) might come in use (disclaimer: never used it myself).

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my initial post to reflect my implementation of the many-many approach, along with a one-many implementation for article-creator relationship. Would you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `has_many :through`, although it will be expensive on the database.

---

A *much* better way will be to use [Redis](http://redis.io/) to store `key:value` pairs for the `posts` a `user` has viewed. There's a [good article about it here](http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html).

I'd do it in the `posts#show` action:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
     # considering you're using Devise "current_user"
     @post = Post.find params[:id]
     $redis.sadd(current_user.id, @post.id) #-> this will need to change
  end
end
```

This will allow you to add a class method in the Post model to get relevant posts which have not been viewed by users:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.viewed(user, viewed=true)
      posts = $redis.get(user.id) #-> this will need to change
      where = "not" unless viewed is true
      self.where("`id` #{where} IN ?", posts)
   end
end
```

--

Now, Redis is meant as a temporary (semi-persistent) data store. This means you shouldn't rely on it for a long term solution. Instead, you may wish to "dump" the redis data into a datatable, or if you're happy to let it go if lost, then keep it in Redis perpetually.

I can give you more info upon request.

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks. By "expensive", do you mean that the join table will be big and query speed might be low?

Redis looks good but since I'm just starting out on writing my first production app, I think I will stick with the db level and incorporate Redis later. Do you think this is a fine approach, or is Redis something you have to design for from the beginning?

Comment: Expensive in db terms simply means it will take more time / resource to accumulate the data. If you're not bothered so much about that, you can use the `many-to-many` approach with no issues at all!

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my initial post to reflect my implementation of the many-many approach, along with a one-many implementation for article-creator relationship. Would you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 0):

You could also create another table called viewings with a user_id, post_id, and viewed flag.